# Gauss's Law and Superposition Principle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, superposition

Hi I am doing the homework in MIT 8.02 by Dr.Lewin, I doubt that the [answer provided online](http://web.mit.edu/8.02/www/Spring02/problemsets/pss1.pdf) for Problem set is wrong, here is the problem.

[image]

For question(a)(b)(c)

[image]

it answers 
[image]
For me, I think the Region(1) and Region(3) should have opposite sign. Because the electric field of the negative sheet should point downside, and that of the positive slab should point upside. Thus, it should replace the plus sign with the subtract sign. I am confused that why the superposition of the two electric fields in the Region I(III) is to use the summation of both electric fields instead of the difference? You can help me a lot if you can answer this question for me~ For its detailed answer please look at the last two pages of this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VkivTrNQVxYSM1C3NCnp0SdqAonYOAc5/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution to your dilemma is in the following graph.

[image]

The $\sigma$ in the derivation by Professor Lewis was the surface charge density and it could have been a positive or negative quantity, ie it he found a general result for the electric field due to a surface charge density which could be numerically positive or negative.

When the graph was drawn the label $-|\sigma|/2\epsilon_0$ for the electric field for $z>0$ shows that in this example the surface charge density was in fact a negative quantity as $|\sigma|$ must have a positive value.

In your derivation you accounted for the fact the the surface charge density was negative right at the start by writing the surface charge density as $-\sigma$ with $\sigma$ a positive quantity.